# Changing Three.js displacement map shader to use all rgb values not just red

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I am trying to modify the displacement map to take an rgba texture to show displacement value with 32 bits precision instead of the 8 bits precisions used by default in three.js displacement map so I can see tiny differences of height on my terrain in the context of a flooding visualisation.

When I modify the displacement map shader function in the Three.js package in three.js-master\src\renderers\shaders\ShaderChunk\displacementmap_vertex.glsl , I replace :

```
transformed += normalize( objectNormal ) * ( texture2D( displacementMap, uv ).x * displacementScale + displacementBias );
```

by:

```
transformed += normalize( objectNormal ) * ( (texture2D( displacementMap, uv ).r*256.0*256.0*256.0)+(texture2D( displacementMap, uv ).g*256.0*256.0)+(texture2D( displacementMap, uv ).b*256.0)+(texture2D( displacementMap, uv ).a)) * displacementScale + displacementBias );
```

But the result looks weird compared to an 8 bits displacement map. 
The 8 bit displacement map looks like that: 
[image] 
The 32 bits displacement map looks like that:
[image]
As if some portion of the information contained in the 32 bit height was lost, or changed as bumps and holes that did not exit before are being created. How should I encode displacement over all four channels instead of just red ?

The textures I use as input for my displacement map are: 
the png with height encoded in the red channel:

[image]

the png with height encoded in the all four channels:

[image]

The code in which I create the mesh with a displacement map looks like this:

```
displacementMap0 = textureLoader.load( list_depth_images[0],function ( mt0) {
displacementMap0.wrapS = displacementMap0.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;    
addPlanes();
```

});

```
function addPlanes(){
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0x88ffaa,
    normalMap: normalMap,
    normalScale: new THREE.Vector2( 1, 1 ), // why does the normal map require negation in this case?
    aoMap: aoMap,
    aoMapIntensity: 0.5,
    specularMap: specularMap,
    specular: 0x222222,
    displacementMap: displacementMap0,
    displacementScale: ((settings.displacementScale)*overall_scale)/(256.0*256.0*256.0),
    displacementBias: 0.0,// from original model
    side: THREE.DoubleSide //,transparent: true, opacity:0.5//, wireframe: true
});
var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000*2*overall_scale, 2000*2*overall_scale,1000, 1000);
THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.computeTangents( planeGeo );
plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeo, material );
plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
plane.position.y = -400.0*overall_scale;
scene.add( plane );
```

}

I have a functionning working example of the code here with the 8 bits displacement and the faulty 32 bits one : [downloadable .zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4A9h6rjowNGRDVlMGtTRnRZMlk)

Comment: Please post a picture of how it looks. And also, can you show what the contents of the displacementMap is? It might be the culprit.

Comment: I have added more info in the post - to answer your post, I am not sure how I can show the content of the displacementMap otherwise than with the images above...

Comment: for the unpacking consult three's packing shaders, you can get rid of a lot of instructions by doing a vector product.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. my textures were inverted (ABGR instead of RGBA)!!  So the shader I rewrote by using the packing shader in Three.js works as it should...
The new shader code looks like this :

```
const float UnpackDownscale = 255. / 256.; 
const vec4 UnpackFactors = UnpackDownscale / vec4(256. * 256. * 256., 256. * 256.,  256. ,1.);
transformed += normalize( objectNormal ) * (dot(texture2D( displacementMap, uv ).rgba,UnpackFactors) * displacementScale + displacementBias );
```

It now looks smooth...
See: 
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how you got all four channels to load from a png? I was never able to do this.

Comment: I am still not 100% sure I did everything correctly, but, I have updated the link to the .zip file in the text above to have what I hope is a good solution.

Comment: Ok. The whole thing now works for 32 bits displacement map as long the input file is in RGBA format...